# How std::transform is initializing the functor with a specific value?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the below program in which the counter value should be initialized with a specific value in the `increment` class's constructor.

But how this is possible when it is used as a functor in `std::transform`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class increment
{
    int counter;
public:
    increment(int val) : counter(val) {}
    int operator()(int inc_val)
    {
        return (counter + inc_val);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    int step = 2;
    std::transform(arr, arr + n, arr, increment(step));

    for(auto i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    std::cout << "arr[" << i << "] : " << arr[i] << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is it possible that an instance of a class stores data? If that's confusing, I think you need to go back to basics here, take classes, read introductory programming books, etc.

Comment: A class doesn't store data. An instance of the class does, and you're passing one such instance of the class to `std::transform`.

Comment: In the above program how it is possible to initialize counter with a specific value, so that after increment it will be reflected in the array values?

Comment: The way I interpret your question, the code you provided already does that.

Comment: Why not use lambda instead and initialise member variable

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik, My question is simple here, while passing one such instance to the class how can I initialize the counter value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the counter value should be initialized with a specific value ...

Your `increment` functor **is** initialized with a specific value, which in this case is `step`.

```
std::transform(arr, arr + n, arr, increment(step));
```

Passing a **functor** is not something special, but merely create an temporal *callable* object, and pass that *callable* object.

If that confuses you, does this following code look somewhat clearer to you?

```
// Create the variable named my_functor
increment my_fuctor { step };

// Pass my_functor to std::transform
std::transform(arr, arr + n, arr, my_fuctor);
```

Comment: @sureshm It's actually pronounced as *Seo*, not *Sao*. :)

Comment: @sureshm No worries. :)